# Representing a double as an array of characters in C

Tags: c, gtk, double

I am working with GTK, and in my program I am taking a user input, converting it from a string to a double using atof() in order to make computations, and then outputting the result into an entry. My problem is when using

```
void gtk_entry_set_text( GtkEntry *entry, const gchar *text );
```

I obviously need to pass the second argument as a gchar (or just a regular pointer to an array of characters), but I am not sure how to convert my double back into a human readable representation of the double. For example, user enters 65.0. I convert the string "65.0" to a double 65.0, perform my function (say multiply by two), and now I need to convert the double 130.0 into "130.0", and then store it into a character array to be passed into gtk_entry_set_text. How can I achieve this?

To help clarify as much as possible, here is the code in question.

```
/* function for calculating optimal amount of cash to bet */
static void calculateRatioOfCash()
{
    const gchar *userInput;
    char outputString[BUFSIZ];

    /* retrieve probability of winning from input field */
    userInput = gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY(entry));

    /* convert our probability in str to a double and compute betPercentage */
    double betPercentage = 2*(atof(userInput)) - 100;

    outputString = /* what code goes here ?? */

    gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(outputField), outputString);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`sprintf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/). Something like this:

```
sprintf(buf, "%lf", a)
```

[Sample](http://ideone.com/RLe7le).

```
sprintf(outputString, "%lf", betPercentage)
```

Comment: That would only help me in printing it to stdout, stderr, or whatever, right? I need to store it into a character array so I can pass a pointer to that array as my second argument in gtk_entry_set_text.

Comment: @RandyBanks: `buf` is a char array buffer. See the sample attached in edit.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using GLib already, I'd suggest using [GLib string utility functions](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-String-Utility-Functions.html). In this case:

```
char *output = g_strdup_printf ("%f", betPercentage);
```

This is easier than using sprintf() because it allocates memory for you -- of course it means you should `g_free (output)` when you're done with it.